# Energy required to stop a rotor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, rotational-dynamics, inertia

If I want to stop a rotor going 8750 rpm with a moment of inertia .0325 kg m^2 then do I just calculate the kinetic energy the rotor has and that's my answer? and if so would I make it negative

Answer (score 2):

You are right! In order to stop the rotor, you need to do the work (e.g. by a brake) corresponding to its rotational energy. You just calculate the rotational energy $E_{rot}=\frac{I\omega^2}{2}$, where I is the moment of inertia and $\omega$ is the angular velocity. This energy is the energy (work) you need to stop the rotation. You can just give the positive value.